# Move an element left on each click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think My main question is "how do I write this?" 
Its a simple thing. for every click the css left property gets 500px taken off. (moved 500px to the left)

I am having a hard time with the variables and just ... I don't know.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    var belt-move = 500;
    var belt-ammount = $(".belt").css('left');
    belt-move -=  belt-ammount;


     $(".next").click(function() {
        $(".belt").animate(belt-move, 500, "swing");
     });
});
```

Comment: One of the reasons people provide free help on StackOverflow is to help build a curated archive of programming questions and answers. That's one of the founding goals of this site. Please help make that possible by giving your question a meaningful title. "Jquery operations (easy question)" says nothing about your question, and doesn't help anyone who wants to do the same thing in the future find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all JavaScript (ECMAScript) doesn't allow minus character '-' in variables names, so you can't use the name `belt-move`, instead you should use underscore '_' (`belt_move`) or camel case convention (`beltMove`).

Second: Defining jQuery animation you need to define what property you want to change, in this case 'left'.The 'swing' easing function is default so you don't need to pass it.

Third: `$(function() {...});` is shorter version of `$(document).ready(function() {...});`

So the final code should look like this:

```
$(function() {
    var beltMove = 500;
    var moveDuration = 500;
    $(".next").click(function() {
        var jqBelt = $(".belt");
        jqBelt.animate({left:"-="+beltMove}, moveDuration);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.....

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    var belt-move = 500;
     $(".next").click(function() {
         var belt-ammount = parseInt($(".belt").css('left'));
          belt-move =  belt-ammount-belt-move;
        $(".belt").animate(belt-move, 500, "swing");
     });
});
```

Comment: I think this line `belt-move -= belt-amount;` needs to be `belt-move = belt-amount-belt-move;`. Otherwise, belt-move will become negative.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line: `var belt-ammount = $(".belt").css('left');` to `var belt-ammount = parseInt($(".belt").css('left'));`. The reason is that `.css` will return with `px` at the end of the pixel, e.g. `500px'.

Comment: That won't fix the main issue, which is that he didn't put the logic inside the click event handler, where it needs to be.

Comment: @Dan-i have written the logic under click event...see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse out the `left` property or do the subtracting yourself - the [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function has this capability built in:

```
 $(".next").click(function() {
    $(".belt").animate('-=500px', 500, "swing");
 });
```

See http://www.jsfiddle.net/ExRR7/ for a simple demo of this